# Store Datareader calculation result in List c#

Tags: c#

I have a method that calculates cost for my project however the calculation needs to be performed for each row in my database, once the calculation has been done I want to store it in a list but I'm getting errors.

so far I have:

```
string Query = "SELECT p.PID, p.PName, (p.Weight * b.Foodcost) + p.VetBill 
                + b.Housing AS TotalCost FROM pet p INNER JOIN breed b ON 
                p.BreedID = b.BreedID";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, con);
List<int> val = new List<int>();
try
{
   con.Open();
   OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read())
   {
      val.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
   }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.Write("Error " + ex);
}
return val;
```

however when i run this, all that is returned is the primary key of the rows it done the calculations for.. how do i solve this? I know the statement is correct because when i run the statement in SQL or Access it gives me the results i am expected to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this...

```
val.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
```

to...

```
val.Add(reader.GetInt32(2));
```

The value is the `ordinal` position, `0` being the first.

Also, maybe consider this...

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
      val.Add(reader.GetInt32(2));//or use reader.GetDouble(2) since its a cost?
else
      val.Add(0);
```

I have added the `GetDouble()` in case you are returning Double, or you should use `GetDecimal()` if using Decimal.

Obviously, if it isn't an `Int`, and you need to change the `GetInt32`, then remember to change the variable...

```
var val = new List<double>();
```

**Edit**: Based on comment of invalid cast

1. Where are you getting the error?
2. What does this 'TotalCost' field look like.
3. Run the query, and check the data. If you have **non int**, e.g. `nn.nn` or `nulls`, then you need to change the type.

Comment: Have you added the check for null? also, run the SQL to check what the `TotalCost` looks like.  Can you dump the data, or a cut down of the data, maybe a few rows?

Comment: TotalCost is an alias that i use to display the totalcost, it is not a column in the database

Comment: yes, but if you run that SQL above...it will give you 3 columns, the 3rd will be `TotalCost`

Comment: using the code you provided i still get the error of Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: got it working, had to change one column from int to double and it now works. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, maybe check your query too.  If the fields are `nullable`, then check each with `ISNULL(field, 0)` **if this is SQL server**

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the wrong column

```
 string Query = "SELECT p.PID,  p.PName, (p.Weight * b.Foodcost) + p.VetBill + b.Housing AS TotalCost FROM pet p INNER JOIN breed b ON p.BreedID = b.BreedID";
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, con);
   List<int> val = new List<int>();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
          val.Add(reader.GetInt32(2));


        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Error " + ex);
    }
return val;
```

Try this

Comment: because it is not a integer maybe.

Comment: Send us you sql table design, my guess is that the column will return a double and not an integer

Comment: trying the GetDouble method is still showing "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: Just edit your post and add the table design, it will be easier to hel+

Comment: @N4TKD got it working, you was right needed to change one of the columns from int to double.

Comment: Your result could be a null, debug it - set a break point - and see what you are getting.

Comment: @N4TKD have checked and results coming out as expected